# Calculated column must be populated with random number

Tags: sharepoint-online

There are two columns in SharePoint:-

Column A (*Expects TRUE OR FALSE*)
Column B (*NUMBER 1 to 10 Depending upon TRUE OR False. IF its TRUE it should Display Number if its False It Should be Blank*)

This I have to achieve it by SharePoint calculated column.

Comment: The RND or RAND(BETWEEN) functions are not available in SharePoint Formulas, you have to create something 'randomish' using the digits in ``NOW()``. Note that Formulas only update on Item or Formula change..  so it might not work as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in Column B.

```
IF([Column A]="FALSE","",[Column B])
```

Comment: I have used same formula but its showing No as text instead of number .